# Flutter compactCurrency for Indian rupees but need to display lakhs, crores in English

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `NumberFormat.compactCurrency()` with `HI` locale as I want to compact the number in the Indian currency way - into lakhs, crores..etc.

But, if I use `HI` as the locale in it, it seems to add the lakh/crore string in Hindi. I want to compact the currency in the Indian way but show the lakh/crore in English. Do I need to use a different locale string for that? any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way to get closest to your requirements would be to use  `en_IN`:

`NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: 'en_IN').format(price)`

### Output :

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73597401/convert-number-to-indian-words-style-in-flutter